# How to start Internet Explorer 8 without any bars

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

At work I use LogMeIn to do remote assistance for our customers.

The only thing which is bugging me is that you can switch to fullscreen mode but it doesn't offer to open the remote session in a new window without address bar, bookmarks bar and stuff.

So I'm looking for a way to open the LogMeIn Tech Console in a new browser window without any bars.

Fullscreen mode is nice but not usable when working with other applications besides the remote session. The Internet Explorer Kiosk mode also doesn't fit my needs.
I created a bookmarklet with works quite nice but having a link directly on my desktop would be perfect.

Does anyone have a hint on that?

I use IE8 on Windows XP SP3.

Thx in advance

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a help desk and we have used logmeinrescue for years. Have you tried dragging your bookmark to your desktop? I do that all the time to create shortcuts. Also, have you tried hitting F11 to put IE into fullscreen mode?

I'm not sure if it is the console itself you want to open out or the remote control sessions but if you log in to your account at beta.logmeinrescue.com there is a beta feature that allows you to pop out the remote control window.

Comment: Fullscreen mode doesn't fit my needs, I want to have a window I can use side by side with other applications and I want to see my Windows taskbar. It'd be enough to have a shortcut that opens an IE window without any bars and loading the LogMeIn Tech Console windows, not the session itself.